# deserialization 'infinity' date in colander

Tags: python, json-deserialization, colander

I'm using [colander](http://colander.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for deserialization and validation json data. 
I need process special values `infinity` and `-infinity` in date fields.
But `colander.Date` doesn't support such value.

```
class Card(colander.MappingSchema):
    card_no = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    expiration = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Date())

cstruct = {'card_no': '12345', 'expiration': 'infinity'}

schema = Card()
output = schema.deserialize(cstruct)
```

I have output

```
colander.Invalid: {'expiration': 'Invalid date'}
```

My working code is:

```
def modify(nodes, kw):
    for node in nodes:
        if (type(node.typ) == colander.Date):
            if kw[node.name] == 'infinity':
                kw[node.name] = str(datetime.max)

cstruct = {'card_no': '12345', 'expiration': 'infinity'}

schema = Card(after_bind=modify)

schema = schema.bind(**cstruct)

output = schema.deserialize(schema.bindings)
print(output)
```

I have output

```
{'card_no': '12345', 'expiration': datetime.date(9999, 12, 31)}
```

But I'm not sure, if it is a good idea to do it this way.

Or should I rather define custom colander type for date fields and use it instead of `colander.Date`?

Comment: I suspect the problem here is that there is no conversion between infinite values and date in Python. Use MAXYEAR and MINYEAR instead, or have a flag to represent whatever you're trying to represent.

Comment: Do you mean that I would use cstruct = {'card_no': '12345', 'expiration': '9999-12-31'}?

Comment: Yes. Also, look at jsonpickle if you want an alternative serializer (disclosure: I'm a co-author).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out jsonpickle library. I'm using colander for validation json data before processing in sqlalchemy. It seems to me jsonpickle doesn't provide validation.

Comment: That's correct. You'd still need to use a separate validator if that's what you need.

Comment: As @Marcin suggested, value '9999-12-31' can be used instead of 'infinity'. I think it is a good idea. Colander can automatically deserialize it and my code remains simple.